# Visual Studio Code: How to close Find in Files pane?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to edit a set of files. I wanted to do a search-and-replace to all of the files in a directory, so I selected Edit > Replace in Files. VS Code opened a search pane to the left of the editing pane.

I found that VS Code was only going to search open files. Rather than stop to figure out how to change that, I performed the operation in another editor.

Now I want to close the search pane. How can I do that?

There's no close box. There's no "collapse" arrow. Escape does nothing. There's a label above the pane that says EXPLORER, so presumably this is an EXPLORER pane, but View > Explorer doesn't toggle the pane off. Even quitting and restarting the editor doesn't make it go away.

Microsoft's documentation tells me everything about using Find/Replace in Files, except how to get rid of it.

I don't want to be stuck with the search pane forever!

Answer (score 1):

You switch the bar on/off with `View | Appearance | Show Bar` (`Ctrl+B`)

If you see `Explorer`  in the bar you are in the explorer bar. The search bar has `Search` at the top.

`Edit | Replace in Files` shows the search bar with the replace field visible

Answer (score 0):

You nee to just click on the search icon on the left panel of the vs code. Yours may be of different colour.

[image]